# Flow: Cannot get ... because property ... is missing in object literal

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have the following code, which should refine the `example` variable's type using JavaScript's `in` operator:

```
type Example = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

const objectWithSomeExampleKeys = {
  foo: 'foo',
  baz: 'baz'
};

function heresTheProblem(example: Example): void {
  if (example in objectWithSomeExampleKeys) {
    objectWithSomeExampleKeys[example];
  }
}
```

But instead, I get the following error:

```
    10:     objectWithSomeExampleKeys[example];
                                      ^ Cannot get `objectWithSomeExampleKeys[example]` because property `bar` is missing in object literal [1].
        References:
        3: const objectWithSomeExampleKeys = {
                                             ^ [1]
```

How do I get Flow to recognize that `example` cannot be `bar` or any other property not in `objectWithSomeExampleKeys`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem:

If I explicitly type `objectWithSomeExampleKeys` from my sample code with `{[example: Example]: string}`, the error goes away:

```
type Example = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

// Explicit type added to objectWithSomeExampleKeys:
const objectWithSomeExampleKeys: {[example: Example]: string} = {
  foo: 'foo',
  baz: 'baz'
};

function heresTheProblem(example: Example): void {
  if (example in objectWithSomeExampleKeys) {
    objectWithSomeExampleKeys[example];
  }
}
```

https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQOQDMD2+2UAPjgEYIBOxZ2lAXtgNwBQrAxvgHYDOwUfOQBWEDsADqAS2AALAMr4kEeMjQQA0hBC8AXFADeAbQiIU6favMQAuvv5Up3AOYBfKFgOsoUAvn14hNgANN5QjAGM2KyubKy4AK7c4lI8ULIQVBC8ACoZAApUQuhIABSmahawZuoAlPoAbvhSACaGYVK4UOU16FBOgiJikjIKSiq9mtq8te0+PkKi4tJyispW6lo6JpM2bD6uMUA

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that example can be `'bar'` because Example is of type `'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'`. This checks out no problem: https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQOQDMD2+2UAPjgEYIBOxZ2lAXtgNwBQrAxvgHYDOwUfOQBWEDsADqAS2AALAMr4kEeMjQQA0hBC8oWAN6soUAvgBcOU9gA0RqIwv0ETW8cpVH77KwC+bVrgArtziUjxQshBUELwAKpEAClRC6EgAFBCIKOgW-FRS3ADmAJQWAG74UgAmUIbGUrhQGVnqUAWCImKSMgpKKi3oWjrFtXbGQqLi0nKKyqrZmtq8ANqZaugAumzGPr5AA

```
type Example = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

const objectWithSomeExampleKeys = {
  foo: 'foo',
  baz: 'baz',
  bar: 'bar'
};

function heresTheProblem(example: string): void {
  if (example in objectWithSomeExampleKeys) {
    objectWithSomeExampleKeys[example];
  }
}
```

Comment: `example` can be `bar` but it won't ever be `bar` within the if statement of my sample code. I was hoping there would be a way for Flow to understand the semantic meaning of `in` or some equivalent way of refining the type.

Comment: Flow doesn't refine based on `in` yet.